# Delete files if condition is met

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, find, xargs

I have the following directory tree:

```
/Directories/
/Directories/somedir/somefile.mkv
/Directories/somefile.rar
```

I'm trying to find a way to delete the .rar file if the .mkv file exists and is larger than 1 GB.

I've use `find -type f -size +1000000k -name "*.mkv"` to find the files. I then presume that either `-exec` or `| xargs` could help with the rest but I don't know how to exit the output of find before passing it to `rm`. In my scenario the output would be `/Directories/somedir/somefile.mkv` and the command passed to `rm` would `Directories/*.rar`

Can I do this with `-exec` or `xargs`. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think both conditions can be checked within the same `find` command. You can, however, do a short script that would make the necessary checks and delete the file if they're satisfied.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find -type f -size +1000000k -name "*.mkv"`; do
  # This would remove the mkv extension
  noext=${file::-4}

  # Parts of directories
  parentdir=`echo $file | cut -d'/' -f2` # This would return 'Directories'

  if [ -e "./$parentdir/$noext.rar" ]; then
     rm -f "./$parentdir/$noext.rar"
  fi
done
```

Not tested, but it would be something very similar to this.

Comment: I'm new to bash scripting, but if I understand correctly the above will for remove rar files with the name name as the mkv file in the same directory. How can I add to the script to remove from parent directory? In my case the directory with the .mkv file is named from the .rar file and the .rar file is in the parent directory of this directory.

Comment: You would just modify the `if` and `rm` lines to be something like this: `if [ -e "../$noext.rar" ]; then` ... and `rm -f "../$noext.rar"`. Bash scripts work the same way as you would do it in a shell, so you can export the way you would achieve a task to a bash script and it should work the same way.

Comment: If you want, I can modify my answer to include these lines.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't the output of find be `Directory/Subdirectory/file.ext`. The above would make that `../Directory/Subdirectory/file.ext`. Would that really work. In my reasoning it would look for the same directory structure in the parent directory and not find a file, but I don't really know.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Instead, you could use `cut -d'/'` along with the `-f` option to cut the result in parts with the `/` character as delimiter and take the parts of the path so you yourself build the new path.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Don't really know how to work it into the script though but I guess this should work `find -type f -size +1000000k -name "*.mkv" | cut -d'/' -f1,2 | xargs rm {}/*.rar` On another note, my NAS where I wanted to run this doesn't have cut so if there's a solution without cut I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example, hope you can solve it this way although this is a solution relative to the path where you put the bash script, so be aware.